# How to make Ajax call after successfully filled the form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I am using jQuery validation. It is working fine, after fill all form fields I want do Ajax call but I am not able to do that. I am getting error. How can I do?

```javascript
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#SubmitForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "address": {
                required: true                
            },
            "username": {
                required: true                
            },
            "mobileNumber": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength : 12
            },
            "userEmailid": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "message": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "address": {
                required: "Please enter your Location."
            },
             "username": {
                required: "Please enter your Fullname."
            },
             "mobileNumber": {
                required: "Please enter your Mobile Number."
            },
             "userEmailid": {
                required: "Please enter your Email.",
                email: "Please enter valid Email."
            },
            "message": {
                required: "Please enter Message."
            }
        },

        /* jQuery.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url :"php/submit_hitachiForm.php",
              data: jQuery('form#SubmitForm').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "success"){
                    $("#success_message").show();
                    $("#success_message").fadeOut(4000);
                }
               },
             error:function(exception){
             alert('Exeption:'+exception);
            }
        });  */

    });


});
```

Comment: Can u update my code where i have to change

Answer (score 0):

Put all the validation:

```
$('#SubmitForm).validate({
    // validation rules
});
```

and after that initialize the validation function like:

```
if($('#SubmitForm).valid())
{
    // make ajax() call here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code

```
 submitHandler: function() {
            /*ajax request*/
        }
```